# Use of dummy and empty jQuery promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I run multiple animations and perform some action when they're complete, using jQuery `promises`:

```
$.when(foo(),  
       bar(),  
       baz())  
 .done(allDone);
```

Each function (`foo`, etc.) returns a `jQuery.Promise()`.

Now say I want to include a function which doesn't animate anything, but its timing is related to the animations - I can't include it in the chain, as it doesn't return a promise.

So I can hack it like so:

```
function qux() {
  if (something) {
    return $(".whatever")
      .removeClass("bob")
      .addClass("fred")
      .append(/*...do stuff...*/)
      .animate({ left: "+=0" }, 0, callback ) // <-- dummy animation does nothing
      .promise();                             // <-- this is a dummy promise
  }
  else {
    return $().promise();                     // <-- this is an "empty" promise
  }
}
```

And now I can chain it:

```
$.when(foo(),  
       bar(),  
       baz(),
       qux())  
 .done(allDone);
```

*This works.* But I'm bending the rules here - are there any gotchas I haven't taken into account, or am I somehow stomping on the fx queue?

**UPDATE**
As per answers below, the `qux()` function can be rewritten as:

```
function qux() {
  if (something) {
    $(".whatever")
      .removeClass("bob")
      .addClass("fred")
      .append(/*...do stuff...*/);
  }
}
```

Comment: As per @YuryTarabanko answer, empty promise is unnecessary: ["If a single argument is passed to jQuery.when and it is not a Deferred or a Promise, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately."](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/). I suppose it works for the multi-argument case too.

Comment: Yes, it works for the multiple argument case, and also with real promises such as Bluebird or native promises using `Promise.all`.

Comment: I would still return an empty promise if I were you, a function should always either return a promise or not. Not doing so is an inconsistent interface in my opinion since calling it should always represent an asynchronous operation.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum check the edit, you mean like that?

Comment: This is _definitely_ not what I meant. I meant I would not return `undefined`. `qux` should always return a promise and the type of promise should depend on what it does. Like in your initial version (the `else` is redundant).

Comment: Wait, if your function is always synchronous - why do you even return a promise?

Comment: Don't know, you recommended to... :) It works without it.

Comment: In that case _never_ return a promise from it. Ok, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are going to use it with `$.when` you don't need to return an empty promise. `$.when` can handle non promises. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/w4aS9/).

```
function promise(flag) {
    if(flag) {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('promise');
            dfd.resolve();
        }, 1000);
        return dfd.promise();
    }

    console.log('promise');
}

$.when(promise(), promise(true), promise(), 15).done(function(){
    console.log('Done');    
});
```

And if you want to return an empty promise you can use `$.Deferred().resolve().promise()`

Comment: Updated question to remove return of empty promise. But the "dummy" promise is still there, I wonder if it's not asking for trouble...

Comment: @BobbyB Well, the answer is the same. If you are going to use it with `$.when` you don't need to return a promise. But if you are going to call it like `qux().then(blah)` you should better take care of it to always return a promise.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. It will execute immediately, but the group's done event will get called after the animatable functions are resolved.

Comment: So the actual answer to my question is that it's "safe": you can shove anything into the `$.when(...)`.

Comment: And if you want to return an empty promise you can use `return $.when();` which is the syntactically simplest way to generate a resolved jQuery promise.

Answer (score 1):

If your function is always synchronous - simply do not return a promise:

```
function qux() {
  if (something) {
    return $(".whatever")
      .removeClass("bob")
      .addClass("fred")
      .append(/*...do stuff...*/);
  }
}
```

You can still use it in `$.when` but there is little point since it executes synchronously. You should not return promises from synchronous functions.

However, if your function is *sometimes* synchronous - it should always return a promise for consistency.

As I said in earlier comments - `$.when` is perfectly fine with non-promises (it will treat them as promises). So functions that might return promises can be used with `$.when` however if it is always synchronous it is redundant to do so.

Comment: No, please do not do that. Do not use it as `qux().then(blah)` or `$.when(qux()).then(blah)`. That's slower and redundant. Instead you can do `qux(); blah()`

Comment: I disagree - in most cases it wouldn't be `qux();blah()`, but `let result == qux() ; if (result.state=='rejected') blah(); else meh(); dada();` Compared to `qux().then(blah).fail(meh).done(dada)` I know which I would chose - especially if we need to pass the result of `meh` or `blah` to `dada`